# C# using Statement equivalent in Swift

Tags: c#, swift

I'm very new to Swift language, I have a C# Background.

and I'm wondering if there is an equivalent code for C# using statement in swift Language

```
using( var a = new MyClass()){
//Code Here
}
```

Comment: You should explain what `using` does. Don't expect Swift programmers to know that `using` cleans up `a` on exit

Comment: Actually, you *have* to explain that using doesn't just ensure the cleanup code is called.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's exactly what using does. It calls `Dispose()`, nothing else.

Comment: @Alexander you keep trying to explain `using` in `defer` terms. It's not. Different languages, different designs, different semantics. That `nothing else` guarantees deterministic invocation and creates an additional scope. It also means you don't need to follow the conventions you need with `defer`. It means that the compiler itself ensures there is a `Dispose` method and that it's always called.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `using` doesn't create a new scope. You create it yourself, explicitly with `{ }`, which surprise, you can do in Swift. **It also means you don't need to follow the conventions you need with defer** Hmmm? **It means that the compiler itself ensures there is a Dispose method and that it's always called** The compiler does this for any method(s) you call in a `defer` block, just the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just put cleanup code in your class' `deinit` method.

In many GC'ed systems (like C# on the CLR), this is discouraged, because the GC is not guaranteed to run soon (or at all). While ARC has other downsides, this is where it shines: Swift's automatic reference counting guarantees that deinitialization is deterministic. This is exactly like [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) in C++.

This technique works even if an exception is thrown.

```
class MyClass() {
    var db = openDBConnection() //example resource

    deinit() {
        db.close()
    }
}

func foo() {
    var a = MyClass()
    print(a) // do stuff with a

    // the (only) reference, a, will go out of scope,
    // thus the instance will be deinitialized.
}
```

You can also use a defer statement:

```
var a = MyClass()
defer { a.cleanUp() /* cleanup a however you wish */ }
```

You lose the standardization of using an Interface like `IDisposable`, but you gain generality in being able to execute whatever code you wish.

Comment: That's not equivalent. `using` will call the class's `Dispose` method on  when exiting the block, even if there is an exception. With `defer` you have to manually write the cleanup code

Comment: Panagiotis, you have to write it manually in your `Dispose` overload too. I don't see your point.

Comment: @Bauss it should be clear. Dispose is a class method that *can* clean up internal fields because it has access to them. With defer you have to repeat the cleanup code. Also the scoping is different. `using` ensures that `Dispose` is called as soon as you exit its block. `defer` doesn't give such a guarantee. You can use `using` to close a connection as soon as you no longer need it. You can't do the same with defer

Comment: **"using will call the class's Dispose method on when exiting the block, even if there is an exception."** Defer will run even if there's an exception. That's kind of the whole point. **"With defer you have to manually write the cleanup code"** And the Dispose method writes itself? Of course you have to write your own clean up code. **" With defer you have to repeat the cleanup code"** Not at all. You can make a method to do your clean up, and just call that.

Comment: Actually the `using` is just a syntactic sugar taht will be translated by the compiler in a try/finally block. This forces the disposing of the object, freeing the memory. No memory is released If you don't dispose the object. In Swift I seem to understand that there's a different approach in handling the memory (RC instead of GC), so you don't actually need a Swift version of the `using` statement because there isn't one. One should learn how to handle memory in the way Alexander explained

Comment: @Phate01 You're correct up until the last sentence. `using` isn't about managing memory. The C# garbage collector does that anyway. It's about non memory resources: file handles, db connections, network sockets, IO ports, etc. C# needs `using` because the garbage collector doesn't have deterministic behaviour. That is, once your object is no longer used, it'll be deleted at *some point in the future*, on the next GC pass, which is almost certainly not immediately going to occur. Because of this, if you have a destructor that say, closes a db connection, then ...

Comment: ... your db connection will remain open for some indeterministic amount of time after your object is marked for deallocation. `IDisposable` decouples object lifetime from that of its resources, allowing you to manually or automatically (via `using`) invoke the clean up process, deterministically. Swift's ARC is deterministic, because it deallocates an object immediately upon the last reference to it. Because of this, the `deinit` is guaranteed to be called when you would expect. So any disposal logic can just go in there.

Answer (score 2):

Just learning Swift and came up with the same question.

The closest I could get was this:

```
   if let UOW = (try UnitOfWork() as UnitOfWork?)
   {


   }
```

It's a bit of a hack on optional binding but seems to work. You will need to make sure your class has a deinit defined as called out above by Alexander. I found that even if my init throws an exception, the deinit method is still called as soon as you go out of scope on the IF statement.

**NOTE:** Make sure you are using weak references if applicable to make sure your deinit actually gets called!

It is probably more Swifty to use a DO block for your scoping:

```
do
{
    let UOW = try UnitOfWork()
    // your code here
}
```

Which has the benefit of avoiding a "pyramid of doom" with your pseudo using blocks (like you'll get in c#)